# ClickOnce - network location and FTP location

Tags: windows, ftp, clickonce

We have a ClickOnce application. Currently all our users are on the local network, so it's perfectly ok that the publishing location is X:\example\

Soon we will have some people at another location that also needs access to the application - and then X:\example\ doesn't work anymore because we don't have VPN :(

Instead, we would like to give these people a FTP location they can download the application from, etc. - and at the same time keep X:\example\ for the users on the local network.

Is that possible? Or is there another way to fix the issue so people can download the application, etc. from both a network location (X:\example) and an FTP location?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is off-topic and should be posted on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com). Technically yes its possible

Comment: It's in Visual Studio...

Comment: Fix what issue? You have a set of local users with access to the FTP X:\example\ and remote users with no access due to network connectivity not available. So is your question is how would remote users have access to the same FTP X:\example\ server?